# How do I sort search results by date in Google Support Forums?

Tags: google-search, forums

Google's official support forums leave a lot to be desired as far as finding helpful information (they really should be powered by StackExchange!)

Is there any way to sort search results by date (created and/or last replied)?  Currently it appears that results are only sorted by 'relevance' and some of the threads at the top are very old.

Bonus points if there is a way to limit searches to sub-forums.  Presently, when you enter a search string in the search field, it automatically appends "more:forum" however if a topic has several sub forums (Such as Picasa, which has Picasa Windows and Picasa Mac), it doesn't seem that there is a way to limit results to a specific sub-forum.

Example is: 
http://picasa.google.com/support/bin/search.py?ctx=en:searchbox&forum=4&query=cpu+usage

This shows results from the FORUM but there is no way for me to a) sort results by date and b) limit results to the Picasa for Mac subforum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using a Google Search instead for this...

To limit the results to threads in a parent forum (e.g. in this case Picasa), use `site:google.com/support/forum/p/Picasa/thread`.

To limit the results to a specific sub-forum, you could add the breadcrumbs that appear on each page to your search query. For example: `"Help forum > Picasa > Picasa Web Albums"`.

To order by the date posted, click **Show Search Tools**, and choose **Latest**. This will order the posts with the newest ones at the top.

Comment: Thanks - can't believe it's this convoluted.  You'd think that SOME Google insiders would recognize how frustrating their forums are...